# Mapping arrays in Firestore documents to Swift structs in a SwiftUI app

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I managed to get the array data from Firestore, but as you can see from the images when I iterate over the orderDetails, the details repeat themselves three times instead of showing the three details!

Could you please check it and help me to know what is wrong with it?

Please be patient as I'm new to SwiftUI :)

Here is the Struct:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Firebase

struct OrderDetailsStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var prodName: String
      var prodPic: String
      var prodPrice: String
      var prodQuantity: Int
    
   
}

struct OrderData: Identifiable, Codable {
  @DocumentID  var id: String?
    var orderStatus: String
      var timeStamp: Date
      var orderDetails: [OrderDetailsStruct]?
    
}
```

Here is the view model:

```
class OrderDataModel : ObservableObject{
    @Published var userID = "malbagshi@gmail.com"
    @Published var orderData = [OrderData]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData() {
        
        
        db.collection("orders2/users/\(self.userID)").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print("No documents")
                return
            }
            
            self.orderData = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> OrderData? in
                return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: OrderData.self)
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Here is the order data View:

```
struct OrdersListView: View {
    
     var formatter: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "DD/M MM/YYYY"
        return formatter
    }()
    
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var present
   // @ObservedObject var orderdetails = getOrderData()
    @StateObject var orderData = OrderDataModel()
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            HStack(spacing: 20){
                
                Button(action: {present.wrappedValue.dismiss()}) {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chevron.left")
                        .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .heavy))
                    //.foregroundColor(Color("pink"))
                }
                Spacer()
                Text("My orders")
                    .font(.system(size: 25))
                    //.fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding()
            List{
                ForEach(self.orderData.orderData) {i  in
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: OrderDetailsView(orderID: i.id!),
                        label: {
                            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                Text("Order Id: \(i.id!)")
                                .font(.system(size : 13))
                                
                                Text("Order Date: \(self.formatter.string(from: i.timeStamp) )")
                                .font(.system(size: 13))
                                
                                
                                Text("Order Status: \(i.orderStatus)")
                                    .font(.system(size: 13))
                           
                            }
                        })
                    
                }
            }.environment(\.layoutDirection, .rightToLeft)
        }.onAppear{
            orderData.fetchData()
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            
       
        
    }
    
   
}
```

Here is the order Details View:

```
import SDWebImageSwiftUI

struct OrderDetailsView: View {
   
    
    @StateObject var orderData = OrderDataModel()
    @State var orderID : String
    
    var body: some View {
         
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ScrollView {
                        ForEach(orderData.orderData) { details in
                           
                                    ForEach((details.orderDetails)!) { orderdetails in
                                        if self.orderID == orderdetails.id {
                                            HStack{
                                               
                                        AnimatedImage(url: URL(string: orderdetails.prodPic))
                                            .resizable()
                                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                            .background(Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.921431005, green: 0.9214526415, blue: 0.9214410186, alpha: 1)))
                                            .cornerRadius(10)
                                                
                                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                       
                                            Text("Product Name: \(orderdetails.prodName)")
                                                .font(.system(size : 13))
                                        Text("Price: \(orderdetails.prodPrice)")
                                            .font(.system(size : 13))
                                        Text("Quantity: \(orderdetails.prodQuantity)")
                                            .font(.system(size : 13))
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                              
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, -10.0)
                    }
                   
            
            .onAppear{
                orderData.fetchData()
        }
        }
        
    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXtkT.png)

Comment: how do u want t show/read them?

Comment: `DateFormatter` should probably be `Date`

Comment: I need to show them as a List of "Orders" then each order has a new View List showing "order Details"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping Firestore data is a lot easier when you use Firestore's Codable support.

For the basics, read my article [SwiftUI: Mapping Firestore Documents using Swift Codable - Application Architecture for SwiftUI & Firebase](https://peterfriese.dev/swiftui-firebase-codable/)

To handle nested data, just define another struct.

Here's how your code would like:

```swift
struct OrderDetails: Codable {
  var prodName: String
  var prodPic: String
  var prodPrice: String
  var prodQuantity: Int
}

struct OrderData: Codable {
  var orderStatus: String
  var timeStamp: Date
  var orderDetails: [OrderDetails]?
}
```

Note that I marked the `orderDetails` array as optional, to prevent the mapping from breaking in case the attribute doesn't exist on your document.

Here's the view model:

```swift
class OrderDataModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var userID = "malbagshi@gmail.com"
  @Published var orderData = [OrderData]()
    
  private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
  func fetchData() {
    db.collection("orders2/users/\(self.userID)").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
    guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
      print("No documents")
      return
    }

    self.orderData = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot -> OrderData in
      return try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: OrderData.self)
    }
  }
}
```

(As a side note - class names should always start with an uppercase letter.)

And the view:

```swift
struct OrderDetailsView: View {
    
  @Environment(\.presentationMode) var present
    
  @StateObject var orderData = OrderDataModel()

  var body: some View {
    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
      List {
        ForEach(orderData.orderDetails) { details in
          VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Text("\(details.orderStatus)")
            Text("\(details.timeStamp)")
          }
        }
      }
    }
    .onAppear{
      orderData.fetchData()
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: after looking at Mohammed's code, it turned out the actual issue for seeing duplicate entries in the list was that the document IDs on the order details weren't unique. As `List` requires all items to be unique, this issue results in unpredicted behaviour. The best solution is to make sure the document IDs are unique.

Comment: It made me more confused!  I tried to use your suggestion but I did not know how to extract the data from it.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the piece where to fetch the data from Firestore.

Comment: I updated my answer, I'm getting an error: Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

Comment: Oh, sorry - I see the problem. In your view, you try to access orderData.orderDetails as a sequence. However, `orderData` is an array of `OrderData`, so you can't do that. You first have to iterate over the `orderData` elements.

Comment: I updated the code as per your advice, but there is a small issue. can you look at it, please?

Comment: Try removing this condition: `if self.orderID == orderdetails.id {`. As the `orderDetails` dictionaries don't have a document ID, the `id` value will always be empty. If this doesn't help, feel free to share your project with me via a private GitHub repo and I'll have a look at your code.

Comment: I removed `if self.orderID == orderdetails.id {`. but it made things worst, however, I already invited you on GitHub repo to the code. Thank you  @peter

Comment: Hi @MohammedAlBagshi - thanks for sharing the code with me. I cleaned up the code a bit, and fixed some architectural issues along the way. However, the issue itself is that your `orderDetails` have conflicting IDs. As `List` requires all items to be uniquely identifiable, this resulted in the overlap you observed. You can fix this two ways: specify a different id attribute (see my workaround commit), or (better) make sure all IDs are unique in the database.

Comment: This solved the issue, Thanks a lot @Peter Friese

Comment: No worries - I'm glad it resolved your issue.